# How to change transform:translateX for the react-responsive-carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-frog-18xq8?file=/src/carousel.js)

The problem is when i click on image with fixed width the main carousel  tag translates X to -100%. We want it to translate exactly image tag width.

Here is the [documentation](http://react-responsive-carousel.js.org/storybook/?path=/story/01-basic--base) where i found nothing for my question